# Change and Slide called together jqueryui slider

Tags: jquery-ui, slider

I am trying to create a jquery handle that when you slide it it moves another div inside a container. Following is my js

```
function handleSliderChange(e, ui)
{
    console.log('1');
    var maxScroll = $(".content-item").width()*$(".content-item").length - $("#content-scroll").width();
    $("#content-scroll").animate({scrollLeft: ui.value * (maxScroll / 100) },1000);
}

function handleSliderSlide(e, ui)
{
    console.log('2');
    var maxScroll = $(".content-item").width()*$(".content-item").length - $("#content-scroll").width();
    $("#content-scroll").animate({scrollLeft: ui.value * (maxScroll / 100) }, 10);
}

    $("#content-slider").slider({
        animate: true,
        slide: handleSliderSlide,
        change: handleSliderChange
    });
```

So when I click on the bar both handleSliderChange and handleSliderSlide are called, but when i drag the slider it works fine any solution ? I don't mind cancelling the click function from the slider i only need the drag anyways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to that, the trick is to check prior to running the methods for what type of event is triggered. This is how i did it

```
sliderBar.slider({
                start: checkType,
                animate: options.animateSpeed,
                slide: handleSliderSlide,
                step: options.step,
                change: handleSliderChange,
                });

function checkType(e){
            _isSlide = $(e.originalEvent.target).hasClass("ui-slider-handle");
        }
```